# Are there any Scala libraries/implementations/projects on bitcoin?

Tags: development, library, scala

There are quite a few Java libraries and I am building my Scala code on BitcoinJ, but obviously, native Scala libraries would be quite a bit more elegant. Has anyone tried?

Comment: Per the [Area 51 example questions](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30763/bitcoin/30785#30785),  programming questions are off-topic here and should be asked on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: @eMansipater Well, that example is about urllib vs urllib2. This is about bitcoin libraries. I think that the users of this site can provide a much better answer to this question than people at Stack Overflow.

Comment: I think it should be on topic. http://meta.bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/103/should-questions-about-programming-bitcoin-applications-be-on-topic

Comment: As currently rephrased I am voting to re-open.

Comment: A scala library would be great. Although bitcoinj is a great software, the complexity of Java makes hard to hack into. Note that I have used bitcoinj in Scala without any problems.

Answer (score 2):

I really don't think it's needed. Bitcoin is a complicated project, it's better to have one canonical JVM-based library than a library in each JVM language.

AFAIK there is currently no Scala library, and I'm betting there won't be for some time (unless perhaps as a wrapper to bitcoinj?)

Answer (score 2):

This an old question, but there is an implementation now:

https://github.com/bitcoin-s/bitcoin-s-core

Answer (score 1):

**As far as I know there are no Scala Bitcoin libraries currently under development.**

As @ripper234 suggests, you could make do with the (canonical) [BitCoinJ](http://code.google.com/p/bitcoinj/) library which is currently under heavy development. This approach is often the case with JVM languages, whose primary purpose is to leverage the quality of the underlying support libraries rather than reinventing the wheel.

However, given that Scala [now has a .Net implementation](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/168), then this argument becomes weaker. Therefore I would take the stance that **there is room for a native Scala implementation**, just as there is one for C# ([BitCoinSharp](http://code.google.com/p/bitcoinsharp/)).

Although slightly off-topic [this forum discussion of a C reference library](http://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=14043.0;all) (not C++/C#) brings up some interesting ideas - does it skim over a Scala library in passing.

Answer (score 0):

You could also check out my project: https://github.com/colinrgodsey/scalaminer

Looking to expand functionality too